# Home Alarm System Wire Box Placement

Tags: security, alarm

I have a new home construction and the home alarm system is being installed.  I would like recommendations on the placement of the System Box.  I'm thinking in a closet, and mounted on the wall up high near ceiling (10' Ceiling).  My thoughts are if a burglar was to attempt to tamper with the box it would be difficult to get to it that high.  Does anyone have any other suggestions or recommendations?

Thank you Miles

Comment: The two relevent factors are if the local alarm is loud and lights the house up bright, the perpetrator won't stay around long enough to find the box.  If it's a silent alarm, they likely won't touch the box even if they do find it because they don't think it caught them and tampering with it may trigger the alarm.

Comment: Just don't mount it on the outside of your house (Like they do in movies). ;)

Comment: I bought a unit myself where the box is the main panel. It contains an intrusion detection system which will set the alarm off immediately if it's armed and removed from the wall. If your box has a proper anti-intrusion detection, where you place the box doesn't matter

Answer (score 1):

Generally the location is a mix of what is easiest to cable to, some locations may be more difficult to get access to.

Also then what is the most secure location and also an area that looks the best.

So say if it was a business the alarm panel typically may go in somewhere like the safe room, comms room or a services riser. Domestic installs typically go in robes or cupboards.

So considerations are:

- Making it less available to any possible intruders either when they
  have broken in or if they are casing somewhere. If they intend to try
  to tamper with it make it harder for them to get to and to know about
  and find in the first place.
- Making it more secure or harder to get to by putting it in a more
  secure location, physically secure such as in a room with a strong
  door, better quality locks or so on. Also in an area with electronic
  security such as being in a room with sensors so they will set off
  detectors before they are even in front of the panel. Panels do
  typically have tamper detection however there are often ways around
  it, so this is where it being covered by a sensor applies.
- Realistically putting it somewhere that is actually possible to
  cable, some installs may be extremely difficult to do certain locations.
- Aesthetics wise, installing it somewhere unobtrusive where you are
  not looking at an ugly box all the time.
- Somewhere it can actually be worked on by a tech, generally
  will not be worked on often but sometimes you get locations where the
  panel is put somewhere extremely difficult to find (like a  hot dusty
  roof space) or get access to (such as you can't even get the door
  open). This will hamper any technician working on it.

It's always a compromise of some sort between these points, your suggested location sounds fairly typical so would likely be a good bet.